# Multiple principals contain a matching Identity in Active Directory

Tags: c#, active-directory

I am trying to import data from out Active Directory to a SQL Server table and I am building a list to populate a data table with to run a stored procedure.  When I try to build the list  I keep getting Multiple principals contain a matching Identity.  Our AD person has checked the one name that I know of and there are 2 of the same names but one is terminated and the UPN's are different.  He suggested that I filter on Enabled which I tried with this code:

```
                using (PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
            {
                if ((bool)UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, strUser).Enabled == true)
                {
                    using (UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, strUser))
                    {
                        if (user != null )
                        {
                            if (user.Enabled == true)
                            {
                                strEmailAddress = user.EmailAddress;
                                strUSERid = user.SamAccountName;

                                PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> groups = user.GetAuthorizationGroups();

                                foreach (Principal p in groups)
                                {
                                    if (p is GroupPrincipal)
                                    {
                                        strSecurityGroups = strSecurityGroups + (GroupPrincipal)p + ",";
                                    }
                                }

                                strSecurityGroups = strSecurityGroups.Remove(strSecurityGroups.Length - 1, 1);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

If I comment out the if ((bool)UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, strUser).Enabled == true) line the error moves to the if (user.Enabled == true) line.  I have tried everything that I could fid with no luck.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FindByIdentity` will always only return one user account. If you call `FindByIdentity` without specifying the [`IdentityType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.identitytype) then it will search for user accounts where *any* of the identity types match the value you are giving.

If there are "2 of the same names", as you say, and you are searching for that name, it will find both, even if their UPN's are different. To find only one, you would have to search by the UPN or `sAMAccountName`.

Also, if one account's `sAMAccountName` matches the `name` of another account, it will find both and throw that exception.

If you know which identity type you want to search by, then specify it. For example, to search only by `sAMAccountName`:

```
UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, IdentityType.SamAccountName, strUser)
```

This:

```
if ((bool)UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, strUser).Enabled == true)
```

Doesn't help you because you are checking the `Enabled` value of the user returned from `FindByIdentity`. But `FindByIdentity` doesn't return anything because it's throwing an exception.